# How do I request a touch and go and then remain closed traffic?

Tags: usa, phraseology, touch-and-go

When I first contact a tower to request touch-and-go, if I want to remain closed traffic after the touch-and-go, can I say 
'...tower, call sign, location, inbound for touch-and-go and remain closed traffic'?

I learned touch-and-go yesterday and I'm a student pilot in the US.

Comment: Or say it plural: Somewhere Tower: N12345 inbound with Yankee, for some touch-and-goes.

Comment: I would not recommend the use non-standard phraseology such as *"some touch and goes"*. There are plenty of cases where sloppy radio communications has led to incidents or even accidents. If you want to remain in traffic circuit, request closed traffic. This way both you and tower know what to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call inbound for touch-and-go, the tower controller will assume you plan to remain in the pattern until you say otherwise because that is the norm.

If you *don't* intend to stay in the pattern, say your exact intentions, e.g. "inbound touch-and-go, then departing west".

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can request that on your call, generally if you don't the tower will ask how you will terminate/proceed at which point you will request closed traffic.