# Departing from closed traffic

Tags: touch-and-go

I understand how to request closed traffic from the ground, and what it allows me to do ([What does "closed traffic" mean?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/89965/what-does-closed-traffic-mean)).

There's another closed traffic scenario that I imagine to be common. but I'm not quite sure how to string it all together.

Let's say I'm flying VFR to a Class D airport, where I'd like to do some touch-and-goes and then depart.

As discussed in [How do I request a touch and go and then remain closed traffic?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/68505/how-do-i-request-a-touch-and-go-and-then-remain-closed-traffic), I can request "closed traffic" on the way inbound, and let the tower know that I'll be departing (and in what direction).

On my last pass, I would announce midfield (e.g.) and expect "clear for the option". After acknowledging, **should I *also* request/remind tower re:departure**?

For example, should I acknowledge, "cleared for the option, NXXX123 ..." and then add, "... also, this will be my last pass, VFR departure to the north"? Should it be considered (and phrased) as a request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **For example, should I acknowledge, "cleared for the option, NXXX123 ..." and then add, "... also, this will be my last pass, VFR departure to the north"? Should it be considered (and phrased) as a request?**

I would recommend doing almost as you have suggested in your question except I would say **"NXXX123 cleared for the option,  and this will be my last approach, *request* a departure to the north."**

You could leave out the word "VFR," insert the word *request* as noted above, use the word "approach" instead of "pass," and put your call sign at either the beginning of your transmission or at the end.

Comment: Thanks @757toga!